# More than specified number of pods created on deleting a pod

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed Hashicorp's Vault in my Kubernetes clusters on AWS using the Helm chart for it.

The number of replicas in the deployment is specified as `3`.

Out of these 3 pods, `1` was ready(`1/1`) while the other two replica pods were not ready(`0/1`).
I killed the ready pod and while it was expected that Kubernetes will deploy a new pod to replace it, it deployed two new pods.

Now I have two ready pods and two not ready pods. On deleting one of these pods, now Kubernetes recreates only one pod. So I have `4` instead of `3` pods for my vault deployment.
What could be the reason behind this and how can we prevent this?

Comment: Could you provide the configuration your deployment?

Comment: I have used this chart to deploy, 

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/vault  

Used it as it is, just added the s3 storage part and made vault.dev=false

Comment: It sounds like you’re not interested in the actual solution to this (how to I get vault running successfully?) but an explanation for the descrepancy (I.e. why 4 instead of 3?) for that it would be helpful to paste the output of ‘kubectl get pods -l app=vault” as well as ‘kubectl describe deploy -l app=vault’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment is not working because HA (high availability) is not available when using the s3 storage backend. You’ll need Hashicorp’s Consul or AWS’s DynamoDB, or a different backend provider for that. Change the number of replicas to 1 if you're sticking with the s3 backend provider.

As far as why your seeing 4 pods instead of 3, you need to provide more details. Paste the output of `kubectl get pods -l app=vault` as well as `kubectl describe deploy -l app=vault` and I will update this answer.

I can only offer speculation for what it's worth. With Deployment objects there's a `maxSurge` property that allows rolling updates to scale up beyond the desired number of replicas. It defaults to 25%, rounded up, which in your case would be an additional 1 pod.

> **Max Surge**
>
> `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` is an optional field that
>   specifies the maximum number of Pods that can be created over the
>   desired number of Pods. The value can be an absolute number (for
>   example, 5) or a percentage of desired Pods (for example, 10%). The
>   value cannot be 0 if MaxUnavailable is 0. The absolute number is
>   calculated from the percentage by rounding up. The default value is
>   25%.
>
> For example, when this value is set to 30%, the new ReplicaSet can be
>   scaled up immediately when the rolling update starts, such that the
>   total number of old and new Pods does not exceed 130% of desired Pods.
>   Once old Pods have been killed, the new ReplicaSet can be scaled up
>   further, ensuring that the total number of Pods running at any time
>   during the update is at most 130% of desired Pods.

It's possible that deleting the one `Running (1/1)` pod, along with the NotReady state of the other pods, put your Deployment into a state of "rolling update" or something along those lines, which allowed your deployment to scale up to its `maxSurge` setting.

Comment: There is no option for turning off the high availability in the chart. 

Also I deleted the problematic deployment a few days back. The new deployment doesn't have any such issue. So I can't inspect the pods. However I had inspected the pods and there wasn't any visible problem with them. Thanks!

Comment: @UddhavBhosle You're right. `ha_enabled` is a property in the Vault storage configuration, not the Helm chart. In this case you'll probably have to just change the number of replicas to 1 if you're sticking with the s3 backend. Is that what got it working?

Comment: Yes, changing the number of replicas to 1 is a possible solution. Even though I keep the number of replicas as 3, it still works as one pod as always Ready(1/1) while others are not. That was actually never the issue. I was just curious as to what could cause the number of replicas to be more than the specified count!

Comment: @UddhavBhosle I added some speculation based on what you did provide, for what it's worth. I think that's about as much effort as I'll give this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have such problems, you should

```
kubectl describe pod <PROBLEMATIC_POD>
```

and see the the lower part of your output `Events`.

Some reasons for your pods not starting may be:

- no available nodes with enough resources for your requests
- no available volumes
- some antiaffinity rules and not enough nodes, so the scheduler cannot assign nodes to your pods.

Comment: Yes I had done that, 

My issue was not that they are not going in ready state, but that there are more than the specified number of pods running